# The type or namespace 'Http' doesn't exist in the namespace 'System.Web' in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.6.1

I'm trying to create a Web API following this link .
I have exactly added the way it is shown in [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_web_api.htm) article.

But after adding the controller, it is giving me this error for `System.Web.Http` and `ApiController`.

Error message on System.Web.Http :

> The type or namespace Http doesn't exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Error message on ApiController:

> The type or namespace ApiController could not be found.

**Additional Information :**

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional.
Framework : .NET Framework 4.6.1

I have searched a lot about this issue but couldn't find anything solution.I'm sure i'm missing very small details somewhere but can anyone help me here.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: did you add the system.web library as a reference in your project?

Comment: check if `System.Web` and `System.Web.Http` is present in references. Did you select web api project at the time of project creation?

Comment: I have System.Web in the references list. But System.Web.Http is with a warning (yellow) symbol. So I'm guessing it is not able load.

Comment: Also , I tried to search System.Web.Http in the references window. I couldn't find it.

Comment: @t-prisar , I have selected Empty Template. Then in 'Add Folders and Core references' I checked Web API

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It turns out that to get System.Web.Http, I need to install package - `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` from Nuget. After installing, it solved my problem.